# Fetching query from MySQL onto Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I created a query on MySQL workbench, it worked fine, but when I tried to show that query on Java it does not work.  I'm new to this, and using classicmodels Db. The following query that worked on workbench:

```
select c.customerNumber, c.customerName,
o.orderNumber,
d.productCode, d.quantityOrdered, d.priceEach, (d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach) as totalPrice,
e.employeeNumber, e.lastName, ((d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach)*0.01) as commission
from customers as c inner join orders as o on c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber inner join 
orderdetails as d on o.orderNumber=d.orderNumber
inner join employees as e on c.salesRepEmployeeNumber=e.employeeNumber group by productCode;

'486', 'Motor Mint Distributors Inc.', '10109', 'S18_1129', '26', '117.48', '3054.48', '1323', 'Vanauf', '30.5448'
```

**Here is my Java code:**

```
public void query() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConn, user, passWord);
        pdState = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT c.customerNumber, c.customerName,o.orderNumber,"
                + " d.productCode, d.quantityOrdered, d.priceEach,(d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach) as totalPrice,"
                + " e.employeeNumber, e.lastName,((d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach)*0.01) as commission"
                + " FROM customers as c inner join orders as o on c.customerNumber=o.customerNumber"
                + " inner join orderdetails as d on o.orderNumber=d.orderNumber"
                + " inner join employees as e on c.salesRepEmployeeNumber=e.employeeNumbergroup by productCode");

        rSet = pdState.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rSet.getMetaData();
        c = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        DefaultTableModel dtModel = (DefaultTableModel) tblQuery.getModel();
        dtModel.setRowCount(0);

        while (rSet.next()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("UseOfObsoleteCollectionType")
            Vector vector = new Vector();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
                vector.add(rSet.getString("customerNumber"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("customerName"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("orderNumber"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("productCode"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("quantityOrdered"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("priceEach"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("totalPrice"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("employeeNumber"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("lastName"));
                vector.add(rSet.getString("commission"));
            }//end of for loop

            dtModel.addRow(vector);

        }//end of while loop
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }//end of try and catch block
}//end of query
```

Comment: `e.getMessage();` does nothing that is useful. It gets an abbreviated `String` from the stack trace then .. does absolutely *nothing* with it. Better to put `e.printStackTrace();` - which will provide an helpful stack trace to the `System.err` stream.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `group by` clause.  You've grouped on one field, and failed to ensure all the other fields are either uniquely determined by that field, or grouped functions.  Remove the `group by productCode` and everything should work.

I think the reason it "worked" in MySQL workbench is probably that there is an option you can set (but probably should not) that allows improper grouped fields to "work" (I think by just picking one of many values).

As an example of a query that might work, the following should report the commission each employee has earned by product sold.  Since the customer is irrelevant to that information, that table wasn't queried.

```
select d.productCode, e.employeeNumber, e.lastName, 
       sum((d.quantityOrdered * d.priceEach)*0.01) as commission
from orders as o
inner join orderdetails as d on o.orderNumber=d.orderNumber
inner join employees as e on c.salesRepEmployeeNumber=e.employeeNumber
group by productCode, employeeNumber;
```

Comment: Andrew Thompson, Thank you very much for your help, I just replaced e,getMessage() with e.PrintStackTrace() and there was no space before group by, Now it woks fine including group by, I Appreciate your help.

Comment: David G, Thank you very much for your help, I just replaced e,getMessage() with e.PrintStackTrace() and there was no space before group by, Now it woks fine including group by, I Appreciate your help.  Meantime, thank for everyone that attempted to help.

Comment: good... but I really think you will find it is not producing the values you want.  I suggest trying it with and without the group by, and seeing if things make sense.

Comment: David G. I removed group by, not that much differences as it is by default grouped by customerNumber and showed up with the same sequence but just scattered productCode

Comment: @Learner I think you should also try `order by`.  No, it is not grouped by customerNumber, just ordered by it.  Pay attention to the number of rows fetched.  `group by` instructs that all the equal values of that field (or fields) should be combined into a single row.  I think it is **very unlikely** that you want `group by` without using group functions.